# Unit conversion error?

Tags: unit-of-measure

My teacher gave me a quick trick to convert wavelength of radiation into energy of quanta(photon) while studying Planck’s Theory for College entrance prep.

$E$(in eV) $= {1240 \over λ( nm )}$

and

$E$(in eV) $= {12400 \over λ (angstrom) }$

But here’s what made sense to me, and many of my friends:

Since 1 nanometre = 10 angstroms

So,

$E$(in eV) $= {1240 \over λ( nm ) }$ $= {1240 \over λ (10 angstroms) }$ $= {1240 \over 10λ( angstroms  ) }$$= {124 \over λ( angstroms ) }$

Which is actually incorrect.
Even though I used a conversion similar to

5 meters = 5 (100 centimetres) = 500 centimeters

Which is obviously correct.

Why is this the case? Please give me the shortest possible and most powerful explanation that actually goes into my mind, not an essay. I am baffled by this.
Half my mind agrees, while the other disagrees.
And please don’t say that the trick is nonsense(it actually works).

[Planck’s theory Quick review from NCERT textbook.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SmMg.jpg)

Obviously, this issue is not limited to this trick, it could have popped up in many different cases. Give specific and general explanation both, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think writing things like $\lambda(nm), \lambda(\text{angstrom})$ is causing you to misunderstand your own notation. Let's do it properly from the beginning. We have:
\begin{align}
E &= \dfrac{hc}{\lambda}
\end{align}
Now, divide both sides by $1\text{eV}$, and plug in the values for $h,c$ and keep track of all units:
\begin{align}
\dfrac{E}{1\text{eV}} &= \dfrac{hc}{1\text{eV}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\lambda}
= (1.24\times10^{-6} \text{m}) \cdot\dfrac{1}{\lambda} \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Now, we can always write
\begin{align}
\lambda &= \lambda_{m} \cdot (1\text{ m}) = \lambda_{nm} \cdot (1\text{ nm}) = \lambda_{ang} \cdot (1 \, \text{ang}), \tag{$**$}
\end{align}
for some real numbers $\lambda_m, \lambda_{nm}, \lambda_{ang}$. Now, if we plug $(**)$ into $(*)$ then we find
\begin{align}
\dfrac{E}{1\text{eV}} &= \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{-6} \text{m}}{\lambda_m \cdot (1\text{m})}
= \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{-6} \text{m}}{\lambda_{nm} \cdot (1\text{nm})}
= \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{-6} \text{m}}{\lambda_{ang} \cdot (1\text{ang})} \\\\
&= \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{-6}}{\lambda_m}\,\,\,\, = \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{3}}{\lambda_{nm}} \, \, \, \, \,\,\,\,= \dfrac{1.24 \times 10^{4}}{\lambda_{ang}}
\end{align}

---

Here is where I think you were making the big mistake: it is true that $1 \text{nm} = 10 \text{ ang}$, however, we have $\lambda_{nm} = 10^{-1} \lambda_{ang}$ (if your units get scaled in one way, then the coefficients have to get scaled in the opposite way in order to keep the product same). This is what I meant above when I said you misunderstood your own notation; you were probably thinking of your notation $\lambda(nm)$ as being a number $\lambda$ multiplied by $1\text{ nm}$, when it is really $\lambda_{nm} = \dfrac{\lambda}{1 \text{ nm}}$.

**A remark about terminology:**

The general rule is that if you have a physical quantity like energy $E$, and you say "energy in Joules", then what you mean is $\dfrac{E}{1\text{J}}$. If you say "energy in micro electron-volt" what you mean is $\dfrac{E}{1 \mu\text{eV}}$. So, for example, whenever you wrote $\lambda(angstrom)$ in your post, what you should have written is $\lambda = \frac{\lambda}{1 \text{ ang}} \cdot (1 \text{ ang})$, and this is exactly what I called $\lambda_{ang} \cdot (1 \text{ ang})$ in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that $E$ in eV $= \dfrac {1240 \text{ eV } \text{nm}}{\lambda \text{ nm}}= \dfrac {12400 \text{ eV } \text{Å}}{\lambda \text{ Å}}.$

The constant is $h\times c=4.14\times10^{-15} \text{ eV sec}\times3\times10^8
\text{ m/sec }\approx1240 \text { eV nm}=12400 \text{ eV Å}.$

Comment: Cf. [this](https://www.asu.edu/courses/phs208/patternsbb/PiN/rdg/photoelectric/photoelectric.shtml) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant)